# How to Update / Change URL when Popup Modal Loads?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I'm looking for a way to have a popup modal with a form, and whent he popup loads, the URL changes.

For example, if a person is viewing web.com/about and the popup loads, then it will change the URL to web.com/about?utm_form=popup

Is this possible?

Maybe it will add this utm to the URL when the popup is open, and removes it when closed? A plugin would be helpful.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use Bootstrap 3 or 4? Are you already using it? Or another CSS framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap modal so below code is working :

```
$('#myModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function (e) {
  if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Title: "About Us", Url: 'about?utm_form=popup' };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    }
})
```